# Recovering from a HDFStore directory mistake

Tags: python, pandas, hdfstore

I make a new HDFStore and put something in it.

```
In [1]: store = pd.HDFStore('data.h5')

In [2]: store
Out[2]: 
<class 'pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore'>
File path: data.h5
Empty

In [3]: store['a'] = Series([1, 2])

In [4]: store
Out[4]: 
<class 'pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore'>
File path: data.h5
/a            series       (shape->[2])

In [5]: store.close()

In [6]: exit
```

I restart IPython and "by mistake," in this scenario, I try to open my store from the wrong directory.

```
In [1]: cd some_directory
/home/dallan/some_directory

In [2]: store = pd.HDFStore('data.h5')
```

Oops! Realizing my mistake, I `cd` to the correct directory and reassign the `store` variable while sitting in the correct directory:

```
In [3]: cd
/home/dallan

In [4]: store = pd.HDFStore('data.h5')

In [5]: store
Out[5]: 
<class 'pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore'>
File path: data.h5
Empty

In [6]: exit
```

**My Question: What happened here? Why can't I open the store from the right directory after I've accidentally tried to access it from the wrong directory?** Below, when I open the file *without* first opening in the wrong directory, you can see it is in fact there and all is well.

```
In [1]: store = pd.HDFStore('data.h5')

In [2]: store
Out[2]: 
<class 'pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore'>
File path: data.h5
/a            series       (shape->[2])
```

Is this some sort of context problem? I'm at a loss. This careless mistake happens to me often enough that I'm coming to the hivemind. Thanks!

---

### Updated

I do think this is a bug with HDFStore. It seems `cd` is working correctly. Witness this working fine with CSVs:

```
In [1]: Series([1, 2]).to_csv('test.txt')

In [2]: exit

In [1]: cd some_directory/
/home/dallan/some_directory

In [2]: s = pd.read_csv('test.txt')
(...) IOError: File test.txt does not exist

In [3]: cd
/home/dallan

In [4]: s = pd.read_csv('test.txt')

In [5]: s
Out[5]: 
   0  1
0  1  2
```

Following Jeff's suggestion that I try `!cd` revealed a unexpected IPython behavior:

```
In [1]: pwd
Out[1]: u'/home/dallan'

In [2]: !cd some_directory/

In [3]: pwd
Out[3]: u'/home/dallan'

In [4]: !cd /home/dallan/some_directory/

In [5]: pwd
Out[5]: u'/home/dallan'

In [6]: cd some_directory/
/home/dallan/some_directory

In [7]: pwd
Out[7]: u'/home/dallan/some_directory'
```

Comment: it looks in the 'current' directly, I am not sure if a ``cd`` in ipython actually changes it. You are in effect looking at a different file. Try absolute pathing, or maybe ``!cd`` might work

Comment: Is this a bug in HDFStore? (can you do this with to_csv/read_csv?)

Comment: See updates. Why should ``cd`` work for everything except HDFStore?